# BackStack android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, methods, fragment, back-stack

How to popBackStack fragments by tag like this:

- [c]
- [b]
- [a]

If findByTag **[b]** is exist then clear all elements of stack which are above of current fragment.

- **[b]**
- [a]

else If findByTag **[d]** does not exist then

- **[d]**
- [c]
- [b]
- [a]

Comment: You have to write a class for this and extend from ArrayList or another collection. You need to implement only one extra method: findByTag( data )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess what you question is. Here is a link to Google's [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) guide for you that might help.